# Pushing data from AWS lambda to Kinesis Firehose using Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to send data from RDS to firehose using Lambda function. I was able to retrieve the data from RDS using a lambda function. Now I want to send that data from Lambda function to kinesis firehose.

I was able to retrieve the data from the RDS using the BOLD code given in the snippet and the input from the RDS is stored in the variable 'rows'. But when I try to insert the data from the RDS into the Kinesis I'm getting this error.

"errorMessage": "a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'",

"errorType": "TypeError"

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host = endpoint, user = username, passwd = password, db = database_name)

FIREHOSE_STREAM = 'DEMOLAMBDAFIREHOSE'
client = boto3.client('firehose')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * from inventory.report_product')
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        
        for row in rows:
          data = base64.b64encode(row)
          response = client.put_record_batch(
                DeliveryStreamName=FIREHOSE_STREAM,
                Records=[
                   {
                   'Data': json.dumps(data)
                    },
                     ]
                  )
        print (response)
```

Comment: Make available to others the code of your lambda functions, maybe someone will help you.

Comment: Please show what code you have so far. Here's the `boto` documentation for `put_record_batch()`: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/firehose.html#Firehose.Client.put_record_batch

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

1. Remove `json.dumps()` call on `data`. The `put_record_batch()` method expects a base64-encoded binary data object for the `Data` field. `json.dumps()` returns a string.
2. Batch rows in groups of 500. The `put_record_batch()` method supports batching up to 500 records.

Example:

```py
connection = pymysql.connect(host = endpoint, user = username, passwd = password, db = database_name)

FIREHOSE_STREAM = 'DEMOLAMBDAFIREHOSE'
client = boto3.client('firehose')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from inventory.report_product')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    records = []
    for row in rows:
        if len(records) < 500:
            records.append({
                'Data': base64.b64encode(row)
            })
        else:
            # call put_record_batch on previous 500 rows
            response = client.put_record_batch(
                DeliveryStreamName=FIREHOSE_STREAM,
                Records=records
            )
            print (response)

            # clear records and add current row
            records = []
            records.append({
                'Data': base64.b64encode(row)
            })

    if len(records) > 0:
        # send the final batch, call put_batch_record()
```

WARNING: This code example is not tested.